# How to pass NSData/any information apart from Image/URL into Action Extensions in iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios8

Consider I have a class called `Employee`

```
@interface Employee : NSObject

@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *empImageURL;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *empName;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *empDOB;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *empJobTitle;

@end
```

I am able to pass the image/URL/Strings to `UIActivityViewController` class by specifying the type in plist with `maxcount`.

How to pass the Instance of Employee object to Custom Action Extension?

Answer (score 1):

Use NSCoding to encode the employee as NSData and send that.  You'll have to implement `initWithCoder` and `encodeWithCoder`

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder {
    if((self = [super init])) {
        _empImageURL = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"empImageURL"];
        ...
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder {
    [coder encodeObject:_empImageURL forKey:@"empImageURL"];
    ...
}
```

To encode as data:

```
data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:employee];
```

To decode data:

```
employee = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

For more details on using NSCoding, you can see this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1914/nscoding-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-save-your-app-data).

Or the [Apple Archiving guides](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047i)

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for your response. My question here is how to pass this NSData and read the same at UIActivityViewController using Action Extensions of iOS8.